# "Illegal else without matching if" error message c++

Tags: c++

I am doing a programming exercise for my beginner class. The exercise is to write a c++ program that mimics a calculator.

This is the beginning of my code (not the entire code, just the beginning):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int num1;
int num2;

double answer;

string op;

int main(void)
{
    // Write your main here
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> num1;

    //Prompt user to enter an operator
    cout << "Enter an operator (+, -, *, or /)" << endl;
    cin >> op;

    //Prompt user to enter another number
    cout << "Enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    //Determine whether or not addition was selected
    if (op == "+")
        answer = (num1 + num2);
        cout << answer;
    else
```

Regardless of what statements I put after that "else" statement, I am getting an error message that reads "Illegal else without matching if."

BUT, if I remove the preceding "cout << answer;" line, then the program compiles and runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `c++` is not python. Indentation does not mean a scope. You are missing { } after your if ()

Answer (score 7):

Always use scope `{ ... }` with `if` statements and `for`/`while` loops.

The problem is, if you don't use scope, then your `if` only encompasses the next statement underneath it (`answer = (...`). Because of this, the `cout` statement will happen ALL THE TIME, and the `else` isn't associated with the `if` statement. If you always use scope, you never have to worry about this.

```cpp
if (op == "+") {
    answer = (num1 + num2);
    cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `{ ... }` is, formally, a **compound statement**. It's a single statement, which is why you can put it after `if` like that, and it contains multiple statements. It also introduces a scope. But the key concept here is **statement**, not **scope**. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{}` braces on your `if` statement in order to execute multiple statements:

```
//Determine whether or not addition was selected
if (op == "+")
{
    answer = (num1 + num2);
    cout << answer;
}
else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `{}` brackets between `if` and `else` because you have  more than one statement.

This is what the compiler understands from your code:

```cpp
if (op == "+")
    answer = (num1 + num2);

cout << answer;
else
```

What you should do:

```cpp
if (op == "+") {
    answer = (num1 + num2); 
    cout << answer;
}
else
```