# Expected a statement error while using else if

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to see the output but it always returns the "expected a statement" error message. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int const n = 6;

  int A[n] = {1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6}, i, p, x;
  int T[n] = {1, 3, 5};
  int U[n] = {-2, -4, -6};

  p = 1;
  x = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (A[i] < 0) p = p * U[i] * U[i];
    cout << "Test" << p << "\n";

    else if (A[i] > 0) {
      x = x * T[i] * T[i] * T[i];

      cout << "Test2" << X << "\n";
    }
  }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: What line of code gives this error?

Comment: else if (A[i] > 0) returns as expected a statement

Comment: You are missing the curly braces `{...}` after your `if` statement. Put `{` on the line immediately after it and `}` immediately before the `else` line. You also need a semicolon (`;`) after `return 0`.

Comment: This question is similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334029/illegal-else-without-matching-if-error-message-c#comment108503006_61334029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334029/illegal-else-without-matching-if-error-message-c#comment108503006_61334029) however in this question you did not practice proper indentation so I am not sure if you expected the `cout << "Test" << p << "\n";` to be part of the if block or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you are missing `{}`

```
if (A[i] < 0)
{                          // <--- here
    p = p * U[i] * U[i];
    cout << "Test" << p << "\n";
}                          // <--- and here
else if (A[i] > 0)
{ 
    x = x * T[i] * T[i] * T[i];
    cout << "Test2" << X << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, `if` applies to the next **statement**. So when you write

```
if (A[i] < 0)
p = p * U[i] * U[i];
cout << "Test" << p << "\n";
```

the `if` applies to `p = ...`, which is the next statement, and it **does not apply** to the statement after that, `cout << ...`.

To turn two statements into one, use a **compound statement**:

```
if (A[i] < 0)
{
p = p * U[i] * U[i];
cout << "Test" << p << "\n";
}
```

The two curly braces mark a compound statement, which is **one** statement, and the `if` applies to that entire statement.